# Why does pressing 2 keys simultaneously cause repeated KeyDown events that have IsRepeat set to false?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using C# & WPF. When using a KeyDown event handler to monitor for keyboard input, everything works fine.
It all works great when pressing and holding 1 key, or even 2.
The problem occurs when I press 2 keys at the same time and hold them. When I do this, the KeyDown event for both keys is repeatedly triggered, and the IsRepeat value is false. It's repeatedly triggering new events when you simultaneously press and hold 2 keys.

Why does this happen, and how can I make it not happen?
Below is a .net core WPF example where I monitor for KeyDown events and look for A or S keys. I can press and hold A and I can press and hold S and my code will only generate a non-repeat event once for each. I can even press them quickly in succession.
**If I press them and hold them at the same exact time, new non-repeating KeyDown events are generated repeatedly. This is what I'm trying to prevent or learn why it's happening.**

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
 using System.Windows.Input;
    
 namespace TwoSimultaneousKeyDowns
 {
     public partial class MainWindow : Window
     {
         public MainWindow()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }
         private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
         {
             //If A or S is pressed
             if (e.Key.ToString() == "A" || e.Key.ToString() == "S")
             {
                 //Checks if it is a repeat event (repeats happen when you hold the button down)
                 if (!e.IsRepeat)
                 {
                     txtBox1.Text += e.Key.ToString() + " was pressed.\r\n";
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
 <Window x:Class="TwoSimultaneousKeyDowns.MainWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TwoSimultaneousKeyDowns"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler">
     <Grid Focusable="True">
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition />
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <TextBox x:Name="txtBox1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="400" Width="300"/>
     </Grid>
```

Comment: Don't compare the enum value to a string. Always compare it to another enum (same set): `if (e.Key == Key.A)`. Not sure what you observing. You probably got confused by your conditional check. You have inverted IsRepeated and thus won't see any output to your TextBox when keys are repeated. *" I can press and hold A and I can press and hold S and my code will only generate a non-repeat event once for each. I can even press them quickly in succession."*: that's the correct behavior according to your implementation.

Comment: If I press down A & S at the same time using this code, here is the output I get, until I let go:  A was pressed.
S was pressed.  
A was pressed.  
S was pressed.  
A was pressed.  
S was pressed.  
A was pressed.  
S was pressed.  
A was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

> " I can press and hold A and I can press and hold S and my code will
> only generate a non-repeat event once for each. I can even press them
> quickly in succession."

That's the correct behavior according to your implementation.

You are currently not checking for simultaneously pressed keys. You are simply filtering two individual key press events: 'A' ***OR*** 'S'.
The used logic should indicate that your code is wrong. Simultaneously can only be exprssed as a logical ***AND***.

The correct implementation to check for simultaneously pressed keys would be:

```cs
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnKeyDown(e);

  //If A AND S is pressed
  if (e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.A) && e.KeyboardDevice.IsKeyDown(Key.S))
  {
    //Checks if it is a repeat event (repeats happen when you hold the button down)
    if (e.IsRepeat)
    {
      return;
    }

    txtBox1.Text += e.Key.ToString() + " was pressed.\r\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer my question or help. You example code only checks if A & S are held down at the same time. I'm not concerned with checking that. I can press A and hold it, my code only outputs "A was pressed" once. While holding down A, I can also start holding down S, and "S was pressed" will only be output once, no matter how long I hold. The issue I'm concerned with is when I press both A & S down at the exact same time, new unexpected behavior occurs. "A was pressed" & "S was pressed" fill up the window until I let go, and the IsRepeat value is false on each of them.

Comment: I see. I only read "simultaneously" all over the place. Even your namespace is called "TwoSimultaneousKeyDowns". So I assumed your goal is to detect "TwoSimultaneousKeyDowns". The normal behavior is that if you hold a key long enough to exceed the repeat delay threshold, the event is interpreted as a repeated key press. This is handled on OS level. This means you should check your keyboard settings.

Comment: This could even be hardware related. Have you tried to test different keys? You should try keys on the opposite end of the keyboard.

Comment: Yes, tried this. Even tried multiple PCs/Keyboards. I expect it will do it to you also if you run the sample code.

Comment: I just ran your example  code and it behaved normal - as expected.  WPF keyboard input handling would be useless if this simple but common scenario wouldn't work properly. I can't reproduce your issue. If you don't have any other conflicting keyboard event handlers, then this doesn't seem to be related to WPF. This is not the first time I use key event handlers, believe me,  You can try to set up a new empty project and test it again. You can also try a Win32 keyboard hook to proof that it is not WPF related. But I would start with a new blank solution and the WPF input handling first.